# Mongoose rewrite rule for angularjs reload issue on hash removal

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mongoose, url-rewriting

In an application, I'm using AngularJS with Apache and Mongoose Server PHP, I have faced reload problem while removing hash problem. I resolved in Apache Server by adding following code in htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)       /index.html
</IfModule>
```

But in Mongoose Server, I didn't know where to write the rewrite rule and how to resolve it? Any help?